# $_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']

Tags: php

what is `$_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']`?

In my project they are checking `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN']))` and
`if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']))`.

It is always empty. Please help me with this

Comment: this question is too board. please read php manual  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Here's an article about the `ACCEPT` header: https://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers. The header `HTTP_TOKEN` is a custom header.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP_TOKEN is created from the "Token" request header

```
Token: xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER` is an PHP superglobal which, according to it's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), stores server and execution environment information. Take a look at the [superglobal documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: But i am getting as empty . can u give any example as how the output should be

Comment: @namratha `$_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN']` seems to be a custom header and `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` states the MIME (https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) type the browser accepts for his request, for example: `*/*` for all types

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN'] is "token" in request header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozKjg.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).